# Error adding new project to solution in Visual Studio 2010 Path Length

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am a bit baffled.
I am creating a new solutions with some namespaces that are consistent with the framework I am working at the moment.

When adding a new project the total chars is 150 way below 255.

Why do I get this error when adding a project?

"The length of the full path for the solution ,project or item you are creating exceeds the maximum length allowed by the system.You must reduce the length of the name or the location"

What is the rule? How many chars I am really allowed?

thanks

**EDIT**

Just found a link which says that the path is calculated :
see link 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/d614d0ba-eea2-444b-9be8-7fe4fb85a226/

```
  Path length + 1 (separator) +

  Solution name length + 1 (separator) +

  Project name length + 1 (separator) +

  Project name length +

  80 (Reserved space)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Total chars"?  The full path length, starting form the drive letter needs to be less than 255.  Maybe your starting directory path is longer then 100?

Comment: @Attila Myfull path length to be precise is 133 way below 255. However if you notice the computation of the length apparently is not as straight forward as we might think.See link in the question

Answer (score 27):

I found once my project is created, I can then change my project to a longer name. Project name change doesn't seems to have this number of characters limitation.

-- An update on 7/Mar/2018 --
In Windows 10, you can actually disable the Max Path Length limitation.

Comment: I found the same problem exists in VS2012. This solution works! Thanks

Comment: Care to share how to disable the max path length?

Comment: @Alex.S. https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/

Comment: Not working even with registry LongPathsEnabled set to 1

Answer (score 3):

This is just a variation on @Kelvin's answer, but you can create a new project in a location with a short path, e.g., c:\temp. Then move the project folder tree into the framework you're working on.

Answer (score 2):

VS 2013 seems to have the same limitation. However, I was able to:

1. uncheck the 'create directory for solution'
2. Finish typing the full solution name
3. Check the box again

Worked!

Comment: Where is that box located to uncheck?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with VS2010 for adding a new project in existing solution. The easiest solution is to

- create the project with an accepted name (shorter than desired),
- close the solution,
- move the project to desired location by renaming the project folder AND project .csproj file as desired
- manually update the .sln to fix the project name/folder as above (it's just an ASCII file, projects path are easy to find and update)
- re-open the solution (the project should load well) and go to project properties to fix Namespace and Assembly name.

It's roughly the solution suggested in other answers but here I explain it step by step with more details.